# Compiling Pyqt4 program

Tags: python, compiling, pyqt, gobject

I am trying to package a program I wrote (using Pyqt4) into a single executable for linux. I tried using Pyinstaller however it has problems with importing Gio (for settings)

```
from gi.repository import Gio
```

Running the application would give:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Gio
```

I then tried to use bbFreeze. The problem here is that after compiling and running the application, I get this error message:

```
TypeError: GObject.__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

For bbFreeze this is my script I am running to compile the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bbfreeze import Freezer

includes = ["gio"]
excludes = []

bbFreeze_Class = Freezer('dist', includes=includes, excludes=excludes)

bbFreeze_Class.addScript("main.py", gui_only=True)

bbFreeze_Class.use_compression = 0
bbFreeze_Class.include_py = True
bbFreeze_Class()
```

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and Python 2.7. If someone can help that would be great. This is my first time writing Python and trying to compile it (so I am not sure if there are better alternatives).

Comment: Try asking this question at stackoverflow.com. They are more specialized for programming questions.

Comment: I have tried asking, no one answered yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually compile it, but merely package it. Compiling is where you translate your source code into machine-readable object code in the native instruction set of your computer. So for example, you compile C code into an executable.

Python isn't compiled, it's interpreted. But you can still execute them by prepending `#!/usr/bin/env python` to any script and marking it as executable.

In terms of packaging a Python application for distribution, it's a little more of a hassle than you'd hope, but there are [official instructions from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PythonRecipes/DebianPackage).

As an aside, if you're developing with [Ubuntu Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly), it has a command for packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Actually python supports [packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/introduction.html). You better look into [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/) or [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) for packaging your python package. I recommend python packaging to distro specific packaging as it will be usable in any distro. Also have a look at some projects which use these tools for packaging in [pypi](http://pypi.python.org) e.g [Django](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/1.3.1).